# Symbol to show before value JustGage.js

Tags: javascript, justgage

I want to show the '£' symbol before every number on JustGage.js

There's an `symbol` option already but this only added it to the middle number and at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between line 711 - 737 I added in `'£' +` before all of these values and it works like a charm

```
// set value to display
        if (obj.config.textRenderer) {
          obj.originalValue = obj.config.textRenderer('£' + obj.originalValue);
      } else if (obj.config.humanFriendly) {
          obj.originalValue = humanFriendlyNumber('£' + obj.originalValue, obj.config.humanFriendlyDecimal) + obj.config.symbol;
      } else if (obj.config.formatNumber) {
          obj.originalValue = formatNumber('£' + obj.originalValue) + obj.config.symbol;
      } else {
          obj.originalValue = ('£' + obj.originalValue * 1).toFixed(obj.config.decimals) + obj.config.symbol;
      }

      if (obj.config.counter === true) {
          //on each animation frame
          eve.on("raphael.anim.frame." + (obj.level.id), function() {
              var currentValue = obj.level.attr("pki");
              if (obj.config.textRenderer) {
                  obj.txtValue.attr("text", '£' + obj.config.textRenderer(Math.floor(currentValue[0])));
              } else if (obj.config.humanFriendly) {
                  obj.txtValue.attr("text", '£' + humanFriendlyNumber(Math.floor(currentValue[0]), obj.config.humanFriendlyDecimal) + obj.config.symbol);
              } else if (obj.config.formatNumber) {
                  obj.txtValue.attr("text", '£' + formatNumber(Math.floor(currentValue[0])) + obj.config.symbol);
              } else {
                  obj.txtValue.attr("text", '£' + (currentValue[0] * 1).toFixed(obj.config.decimals) + obj.config.symbol);
              }
              setDy(obj.txtValue, obj.params.valueFontSize, obj.params.valueY);
              currentValue = null;
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a textRenderer function to do this. For example:

```
this.chartCosts = new window.JustGage({
    id: "chartCosts",
    value: 12000,
    min: 0,
    max: 50000,
    title: "Costs",
    textRenderer: function(num) {
        return "£ " + numeral(num).format("0,0");
    }
});
```